# Russian equivalents of the French expression "pour un oui ou pour un non"

Tags: выражения, французский

> Tu ramènes toujours tes complexes ethniques, **pour un oui ou pour un non**, dans toutes les discussions, même les plus anodines.

- {literally}: *You always dredge up some complex about your ethnic origin, **be it for a yes or a no**, in virtually all discussions, even of the most harmless nature.*
- {more naturally}: *You always dredge up some complex about your ethnic origin **at the drop of a hat** in virtually all discussions, even of the most harmless nature.*

This hyperbolic expression is used to refer to someone's annoying tendency to insist on doing something with no apparent rhyme or reason, as if on a whim.

> Pleurer, c'est un truc de fille à ses yeux, comme si elles avaient le droit de pleurer **pour un oui ou pour un non**.

- *The way he sees it, crying is a girls' thing -- as if they had every right to shed tears **over any little thing**.*

How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed in Russian?

Answer (score 3):

I think *чуть что* would fit best here:

> В любом разговоре, даже самом невинном, ты, чуть что, начинаешь бередить свои комплексы по поводу пятой графы
>
> Как по нём, плач — девчачья тема, им, типа, можно чуть что — и в слёзы.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens О комплексах - *к месту и не к месту*, о слёзах - *по любому поводу*, *из-за каждого пустяка*, actually *чуть что* is quite good here. Again - we probably need slightly more detailed context, I think.

Comment: Hi. Interestingly, "чуть что" in the following instance cannot translate as "pour un oui ou pour un non", even if you offered "at the drop of a hat" as a possible translation. https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/17747/how-are-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-and-%d1%87%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-nuanced Given that "pour un oui ou pour un non" is only used in negative contexts, maybe it overlaps the meaning of "чуть что" only partially.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens: *And the goode wyf answerde, that she coude speke no frenshe*

Answer (score 2):

> pour un oui ou pour un non

[По поводу и без.]
[По поводу и без.] is the short version of the full [По поводу и без повода.]

---

> maybe it overlaps the meaning of "чуть что" only partially

[Чуть что] is [at the drop of a hat]

But when you use [at the drop of a hat] in your translation of [pour un oui ou pour un non] I feel, that you are wrong. I can not prove it, because I do not speak any French.

> [How are "в случае чего" and "чуть что" nuanced?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/17747/)

Unfortunatelly, noone told you the truth about real difference between

[чуть что] vs [в случае чего].

[в случае чего] means [in case of something]
[чуть что] means [in case of anything at the first slightlest sign of the case]

[чуть что] is the short version for the full [хотя бы чуть-чуть что-нибудь].

[чуть-чуть] = [the slightlest part] or ideomatically [a drop]

1. [в случае чего] does not mean, that you must react at the first sigh of danger. You can wait and try to solve the problem yourself or ask someone else.
   Usually by [в случае чего] they mean backup tool for solving the problem, so called Plan B.
   [Call me в случае чего] means [you can count on me, but I hope, that you can solve your problems yourself.]
2. [чуть что] does mean, that at any even slightlest sign or evidence of problem, you must contact the sayer of this words.
   Usually by [чуть что] they mean the main tool for solving the problem, so called Plan A or the Main Plan or just Plan.
   [Call me чуть что] means [you must call me as your first reaction for appearence of the problem, even if there is no problem and you just felt that something is not all right.]

Can we [чуть что] translate as [по поводу и без.]?
No, of course no.
Because [чуть что] must have [повод] = [reason] = [sigh of problem].
[По поводу и без повода] reaction is allowed in any case, if there is [повод] or even there is no [reason].

---

[По поводу и без.] has negative feeling as in French.

[чуть что] and [в случае чего] have nothing negative, but they have some feeling of problem solving, which can be considered as positive.

Answer (score 0):

[Ни с того, ни с сего](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D1%81_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D1%81_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE) 'without a reason, on a whim'.